# Get AdditionalValues from containerType's instance

Tags: c#, modelmetadata

I have something like that:

```
[ViewTerms]
public class Foo
{
     [Term]
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

my ViewTermAttribute sets some additional values in ModelMetaData:

```
public class ViewTermsAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
        public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
        {
             metadata.AdditionalValues["values"] = someValues;
        }
}
```

and what I need is to get this info from my 'Name' property:

```
public class TermAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
        public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
        {
             containerAdditionalValues = //need to get here;
        }
}
```

Is possible to get values from instance of the container?